# Node Jsreport SyntaxError: Identifier 'err' has already been declared

Tags: node.js, express, ecmascript-6, promise, jsreport

I am trying to create a pdf from a string of html. In my test project everything is fine. In the real-deal, I get the above error - SyntaxError: Identifier 'err' has already been declared - when I call MailService.mailer()

I am catching and logging err because the jsreport render function returns a promise.

```
 const Jsreport = require("jsreport");

 function createJSReportPdf(reportString, report, type) {

   const reportProcess = Jsreport
           .render({
            template: {
            content: reportString,
            engine: "handlebars",
            recipe: "chrome-pdf"
    }
   }).then( (resp) => {

  return MailService.mailer(
    resp.content,
    "ServiceReport.pdf",
    report,
    type
   )
 });

  reportProcess.catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
  });
 }
```

Param1 is string, param2 is object, param3 is string. The error is 
 at MailService.mailer() , which is asynchronous, but I do not need to catch it here, I deal with that in that function, nor do I care about what it returns.

Anyone have any idea what is causing this syntax error?

Cheers!

Comment: Solved: ` try {... catch (err) {

             const err = new Error('Mailer failure.'); ` was happening when I sent the mail, no where near the line it was failing at. Anyways...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where I was sending the email

```
 try {
  await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
  mailSent = true;
  console.info("Emails sent @: " + Date.now());
} catch (err) {

const err = new Error('Mailer failure.');
console.log(err.stack);
```

}

Pretty much in my face, just in a different file, it is friday....obviously